# How to save date data read from excel worksheet using vba code?

Tags: vba, excel

I have data saved in an excel worksheet in the form of time data (HH:mm:ss). However when I read the data from the chart and attempt to save the information the value is not saved correctly and I am given a string that is a decimal.

```
sub generic()
dim s as string
s = Range("A1").Value 'A1 is where the value is stored. In this case it is 7:30:30.
MsgBox s
end sub
```

The output s is a decimal (0.623.. I believe). I simply want the output to be the information in cell A1 as a string (7:30:30). I also cannot affect worksheet properties everything must be done with vba code.

Comment: any feedback to the answers you got below ? if one of them helped you solve your problem, please give them credit and mark their answer as "ANSWER"

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the line

`Dim s As String`

to

`Dim s As Date`.

It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep `Dim s as String`, you can use the code below:

```
s = Format(Range("A1").Value, "HH:MM:SS")
MsgBox s
```